# AspNet Core MVC Routing with Different Parameter Names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, url-routing

So I have defined a default route in my `Startup.cs` that looks something like:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "default",
        "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "api",
        "Api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I'm attempting to extend my default routing to map into my actions that don't use `id` as the parameter name.

For example, I have a method like the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult) Edit(UserRequest request) 
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Previously, we were simply using `id` for this call, but we've since extended security and built some custom `ActionFilters` that do some behind the scenes validation. I've already built a custom model binder that works perfectly fine if we keep the `UserRequest` parameter name as `id`, but as soon as we change it to anything else, the routing fails to map it properly, and instead we just get a null value.

How would I go about modifying my default route to allow multiple different parameter names instead of just `id`?

Comment: You cannot do with a single route. You have to write different route for different route id or use attribute routing.

Comment: @TanvirArjel is there a way to use the exact same route twice then? When I copy and paste the default route and simply change the parameters name to `request`, it doesn't map properly.

Comment: Have you tried with this:  `[HttpGet("{userId}")]`

Comment: Just tell me `UserRequest` is a object or any primitive type?

Comment: Adding the route attribute to the action works fine, but I'd hate to have to add that attribute to hundreds of endpoints

Comment: Oh! Then I have no idea of how it can be achieve! Hope someone will help you.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an issue with your custom model binder? What is a sample URL that should match?